# Error 'string' in class 'Empleado' does not have a type

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I keep getting the error that string in my class Empleado does not have a name type, I looked up one solution, which was to add the header #include string but I still have the same error.  This is my Empleado.ccp code. One thing to note is that this is a subclass of another class called Persona.

```
#include "Empleado.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Empleado::Empleado(int edad, string nombre, float altura, string emp, string puesto):
    Persona( edad,  nombre,  altura)
{
    numEmpleado=emp;
    puesto=puesto;
}

Empleado :: string getNumEmpleado()
{
    return numEmpleado;
}

Empleado :: string getPuesto()
{
    return puesto;
}   

Empleado :: void setNumEmpleado(string num)
{
    numEmpleado=num;
}
Empleado :: void setPuesto(string puesto)
{
    puesto=puesto;  
}
```

Comment: You need to add the content of `Empleado.h`, otherwise it is impossible to know what the issue is.

Comment: `#include "Empleado.h"` Try moving this after `#include <string>`. Actually, if `Empleado.h` uses `string`, then it should `#include <string>` itself.

Comment: puesto=puesto;  does nothing. You may want this->puesto=puesto

Comment: Compilation errors are associated with specific locations in the source file. Which line is reported as the location of `Error 'string' in class 'Empleado' does not have a type`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I finally managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the function return types in the wrong place on all your function signatures. It belongs on the left before the full name of the function.

```
string Empleado::getNumEmpleado()

string Empleado::getPuesto()

void Empleado::setNumEmpleado(string num)

void Empleado::setPuesto(string puesto)
```

Comment: I was thinking this might be the problem. My teacher showed us her code and she had it the way I do right now and her program compiled without errors. Anyways, thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Functions are defined outside of a class declaration with the syntax:

```
returnType classIdentifier::functionIdentifier() { }
```

The `::` is called the scope resolution operator, and in this case, it tells the linker where to look and how to match function declarations to their definitions and calls.